# How to write a simple hello-world web server with pure erlang

Tags: erlang

Using pure Erlang what is the simplest implementation of a web server, showing "hello-world" HTML page?

Comment: look at this - http://blog.foemmel.com/2008/05/hello-world-webapp-in-erlang.html

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Here's a simple HTTP 1.0 web server in Erlang in about 40 lines of code, not counting comments: [https://gist.github.com/vinoski/4996859](https://gist.github.com/vinoski/4996859).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is 575 characters long [web server](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11412/7712) in erlang.

```
$ cat hgolf.erl

main(_)->{ok,L}=gen_tcp:listen(36895,[]),s(L).
s(L)->{ok,S}=gen_tcp:accept(L),receive{tcp,S,"GET "++R}->[F|_]=string:tokens("/var/www"++R," "),case case file:read_file_info(F)of{ok,{_,_,regular,read,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_}}->a;{ok,_}->"500 Server Error";_->"404 File Not Found"end of a->h(S,"200 OK\r\nContent-Type: "++case lists:reverse(F)of"lmth."++_->"text/html";"txt."++_->"text/plain";_->"application/octet-stream"end,[]),file:sendfile(F,S);E->h(S,E,E)end;_->E="405 Not Supported",h(S,E,E)end,gen_tcp:close(S),s(L).
h(S,H,B)->gen_tcp:send(S,["HTTP/1.1 ",H,"\r\n\r\n",B]).
```

How to run

```
$ escript hgolf.erl
```

But there is more featureful web server [inets](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/inets/users_guide.html) as part of standard Erlang/OTP distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The easier way is to use the Cowboy package, they have excellent documentation and the first example is a Hello World! one. You can read it on https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.0/guide/getting_started/